# There has been an error processing the request magento

Tags: magento

My magento sito got crashed after installing an old extension.. Actually the site turned into maintenance mode after this installation. So I removed maintenance.flag file from root folder. But that did n't solve out the bug. Now we are getting "There has been an error processing your request"

How to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did that extension installed successfully? I think it is not installed successfully. So only you got a maintenance flag. The extension is partially installed. Remove the files related to that and try again

Comment: installation was failed,actually,we got error just after that. and removed maintenance.flag file.Now we just want to bring the site back to the original condition.this is what we get in the error page
There has been an error processing your request
Error in file: "../app/code/community/Magebuzz/Featuredproducts/sql/featuredproducts_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'featuredproducts_setup' for key 'PRIMARY'please advise what all database might have affected because of this and what all need to delete/remove to solve this bug

Comment: are you going to install extension related to feature products? If yes, deleted the file related to this extension. The file you have to delete is at the path of app/etc/modules/Magebuzz_Featuredproducts.xml. Deleted this file from this folder. Before take a backup of this file and delete it. Let me know the result of it

Comment: yes i have removed that xml already and deleted a raw related with that extension from core_resource
but still we are getting this error

Comment: Did u clear cache after deleting the XML file?

Comment: Then go to path that mentioned in the error and edit the file "mysq‌​l4-install-0.1.0.php" and check the table name which is mentioned in this way   "-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('news')};". Here 'news' is the table created. So check what is the table name mentioned in that file and delete the related table. Take a backup of DB before do something (useful in future).

Comment: Happy to hear that solution got worked.. Cheers.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to navigate to magento /var/report/
and find this report number, read this file contents

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JohnWillemse yes it does provides an answer, or at least tries to.

Comment: Trying to is not good enough to post as an answer. You have to be sure an answer solves the problem, so that others may profit from it in the future. The way I read your answer is that I feel it should be a comment on the question. If it worked, you can then expand the comment into an answer, preferably including an explanation of why it works. Right now your answer does not explain how to solve anything; only to read a certain file... and then what?